# How to make two plots distinct in python(matplotlib) in same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a simple python program to solve simple harmonic oscillator using both Euler method and Analytical method, but it seems that the two curves fit perfectly(I am not sure how and why?, since they had to be different). Since these curves fit perfectly, I have not been able to make any distinction between these two curves. Even though they fit, is there any way to make them distinct using matplotlib's features. Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
g=9.8
v=0.0   #initial velocity
h=0.01  #time step
x=5.0   #initial position
w=m.sqrt(10.0)

t=0.0
ta,xa,xb=[],[],[]

while t<12.0:
    ta.append(t)
    xa.append(x)
    xb.append(5*m.cos(w*t))

    v=v-(10.0/1.0)*x*h    #k=10.0, m=1.0
    x=x+v*h
    t=t+h
plt.figure()
plt.plot(ta,xa,ta,xb,'bo--')
plt.xlabel('$t(s)$')
plt.ylabel('$x(m)$')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is changing color and reducing the opacity of one plot:

```
plt.plot(ta,xa)
plt.plot(ta,xb,c='red',alpha=.5)
```

instead of:

```
plt.plot(ta,xa,ta,xb,'bo--')
```

[image]

When zoomed in:[image]

You can also scatter one and plot the other:

```
plt.plot(ta,xa)
plt.scatter(ta,xb,c='red',alpha=.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `plot` method twice, like

```
plt.plot(ta, xa, 'bo--')
plt.plot(ta, xb, 'gs')
```

Comment: Thanks, but the curves still don't look that distinct at all.